# Android Realm Retrofit relationship error

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit, realm

I am having an issue getting all of my POJOs and everything setup so that it parses my JSON correctly.

I am fairly new to Android development so the fix could be something simple.

I was able to get this to work without Realm. I think modified my POJOs to extend RealmObject. My issue is with my relationships. My data is setup so I have a WorkOrder class and a WorkOrderItem class. A WorkOrder contains many WorkOrderItems. Without realm I define this in my POJO as

```
private List<WorkOrderItem> workOrderItems = new ArrayList<WorkOrderItem>();
```

When I modify this to extend a RealmObject I start running into issue. I have tried

```
private RealmList<WorkOrderItem> workOrderItems;
```

As well as

```
private RealmList<WorkOrderItem> workOrderItems = new RealmList<WorkOrderItem>();
```

Either way I continue to receive the following error:

```
Error:(831, 82) error: incompatible types: List<WorkOrderItem> cannot be converted to RealmList<WorkOrderItem>
```

I have setup my GsonConverter as suggested in the documentation.

I have read through all of the documentation and everything I can find online and still have not found a solution. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are getting the cast problem! show the  snippet code where you are setting the RealmList<WorkOrderItem> workOrderItems..

Comment: @anderson_acs I think you are asking for my setter method? If so it is.
 `public void setWorkOrderItems(RealmList<WorkOrderItem> workOrderItems) {
        this.workOrderItems = workOrderItems;
    }`

Comment: sorry that's not it! - > where is populated your RealmList<WorkOrderItem> workOrderItems =) !

Comment: @anderson_acs I am using retrofit/Gson to download and parse my JSON into my model. Also the error I am getting is during compilation not run time, if that helps. Let me know if this is not the information you are needing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On request the callback you're probably getting a `List <WorkOrderItem>`
So I think you need to create your `Realmlist <WorkOrderItem>` from your list.

you need have two Objects `WorkOrderItem` and other `WorkOrderItemRealm extends RealmObject`

For instance :

```
List<WorkOrderItem> mWorkOrderList...
RealmList<WorkOrderItem> mRealmList... //WorkOrderItem need to be a RealmObject


...new Callback<List<WorkOrderItem> mWorkOrderList>() {

    @Override
    public void success(List<WorkOrderItem> mWorkOrderList, Response response) {

        for(WorkOrderItem mWorkOrderItem : mWorkOrderList){

            //create WorkOrderItemRealm
            WorkOrderItemRealm mWorkOrderItemRealm = realm.createObject(WorkOrderItemRealm.class); 

            //mWorkOrderItemRealm.set...(mWorkOrderItem.get...());

            mRealmList.add(WorkOrderItemRealm);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

    }
});
```

Comment: OK, I will give this a try. Will I also need a WorkOrderClass and a WorkOrderClassRealm? Or do I only need the second class when I have a relationship. Also, I have full control to change my API. Is it possible to make changes to my JSON structure so that I only have to have one class instead of 2?

Comment: yeah! `WorkOrderClassRealm` too!

Comment: That worked! It seems like there should be an easier way. Where I can use the same class for Retrofit and for Realm.